# Comparison of binary outcome between more then two groups

Tags: statistical-significance, binary-data

I have a binary outcome (Mistake made? yes/no) and four groups of students (Group A, B, C and D). Which statistical test would best fit to compare the rate of mistakes made between the groups?
Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: You need to add some more information to your question. In particular, how many students are there in each group. If your software won't do a test, you should also describe whatever comment you got.

Comment: What would you do for a continuous outcome, say four normal distributions instead of four binary distributions?

Answer (score 2):

Chi-squared test of independence. You have two categorical variables (group and mistake made) and want to test if there is a degree of association between the two. If you fail to reject the null hypothesis, then this means that there is no association between them (i.e. belonging to a certain group is not related to having a larger tendency to make mistakes).

ADDITION:

The values of the variables in a chi-squared test don't matter. What you have in this test are categories (whether you name the category "Made a Mistake" or "1" is irrelevant here). First, you create a contingency table between the two categorical variable classes to measure frequencies. Then, these frequencies are compared to the calculated expected frequencies, to see if there is an actual difference between groups. It is true however that all frequencies must be at least 5 or higher for the test to work (this threshold varies depending on who you ask).

Also, if you try this on a software and it tells you that values must be at least 1 for the test to work, this is related to frequencies (not the actual values of the categorical variables). Frequencies must be of at least 1. But whether the value of the variable behind this frequency is "0", or "1" or "apples", doesn't matter. Frequencies are frequencies, regardless of the value of the categorical variable they account for.

Comment: Thank you! Graphpad told me that Chi-squared can only be used if the values are higher than 1 (which is not the case as they are either 0 or 1). On top of that, one of the four groups only contains 10 entries, wheres the other three groups contain 20 entries. Is it still possible to use the Chi-squared test?

Comment: The value in a chi-squared test doesn't matter. What you have in this test are categories (whether you name the category "Made a Mistake" or "1" is irrelevant here). Then, you create a contingency table between the two categorical variable classes to measure frequencies. Then, these frequencies are compared to the calculated expected frequencies, to see if there is an actual difference between groups. It is true however that all frequencies must be at least 5 or higher for the test to work (this threshold varies depending on who you ask).

Comment: Maybe what you read is that frequencies must be higher than 1. And this is true. But whether the value of the variable behind this frequency is "0", or "1" or "apples", doesn't matter. Frequencies are frequencies, regardless of the value of the categorical variables they account for.

Comment: @LevG It might be worth editing your comments into the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, will do!